# Custom manifest added multiple times in -post-jar in a common dependency

Tags: java, ant, netbeans-8

I have a multi-module native Netbeans Java EE project. In it I have a `Java Class Library` project that is used by multiple other projects which in turn are packaged into the root `.ear` project.

I'm adding the "build timestamp" and the "build user" attributes to a custom manifest using the library's `build.xml`:

```
<target name="-post-jar">   
    <jar destfile="${dist.jar}" update="true">
        <manifest>
```

When I "clean and build" the root project, each project that refers the library calls:

```
<ant antfile="${call.script}" target="jar">
```

And my `-post-jar` target is called multiple times. This wouldn't be a problem, but sometimes the second invocation of the `<jar>` task fails with `Unable to rename old file` (probably due to Netbeans scanning the files in background, but I can't tell for sure).

There are repeating pairs of `Building jar` and `Updating jar` messages in Ant's output. However, if I remove my `-post-jar` target, the second invocation of the `jar` target does nothing, because it thinks that the jar is up to date and I see only one `Building jar` message.

How do I mark the updated jar up to date, so the second invocation of the `jar` target does nothing?

There's a [github repo](https://github.com/basinilya/postjar) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to *not* re-generate the manifest every time, but I found a way to make the generated file look the same as the zipped file (and we know that the `<jar>` task doesn't repack when the contents are the same).

Instead of updating the zipped manifest in `-post-jar` I now update the source file in `-pre-jar`. This way the final version of the manifest is zipped and since its contents don't change during build, subsequent `<jar>` invocations update nothing.

It worth mentioning that before adding the attributes `Main-Class`, `Profile`, etc. the `build-impl.xml` of Netbeans creates an empy manifest template, if the user doesn't provide a valid path in the `manifest.file=` property. The addition happens *after* `-pre-jar`, however the existence of the user-provided manifest is checked much earlier, during the `init` target and the result is saved to the `manifest.available` property.

My manifest template is not a static file. It contains the "build timestamp" and the "build user" attributes. Therefore the file doesn't exist during the `init` target, so I had to add the following line at the beginning of my `build.xml`:

```
<property name="manifest.available" value="true"/><!-- It will be available by the time we need it -->
```

Secondly, `manifest.file` still has to be set and I set it in `project.properties` (there's no UI for that setting yet and I wonder how it would behave in the presence of the variable in path)

```
manifest.file=${build.dir}/manifest.tmp
```

Next, I overwrite the manifest template in the `-pre-jar` target:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="current.time" pattern="HH:mm:ss" locale="de,DE"/>
</tstamp>

<target name="-pre-jar" >
        <manifest file="${manifest.file}">
            <attribute name="MyApp-built-time" value="${current.time}"/>
            <attribute name="MyApp-built-by" value="${user.name}"/>
        </manifest>
```

After that, the new problem became obvious: the timestamp was different for each invocation of

```
<ant antfile="mylib/build.xml" target="jar">
```

in the multi-module project and Ant had to repack the jar with the new timestamp in the manifest. I solved this by defining the timestamp property in every project's `build.xml`. Although the properties are not inherited due to `inheritall="false"`, Netbeans allows for overcoming that:

```
<property name="transfer.current.time" value="${current.time}"/>
```

This mechanism is broken in Java EE projects, but the workaround is simple:

```
<presetdef name="ant">
    <!-- workaround transfer.* not working in Java EE projects -->
    <ant>
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref prefix="transfer."/>
            <mapper from="transfer.*" to="*" type="glob"/>
        </propertyset>
    </ant>
</presetdef>
```